# how to Validate json file using laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I need to validate json file only when user upload from browser but doesn't works ,it works when i combined with txt file.
working code source

```
 $this->validate($request, [
                // check validtion for json 
                'dataset_type' => 'required|mimes:json,txt'
            ]);
```

what i need is to validate json file only below code doesn't works

```
$this->validate($request, [
                // check validtion for json 
                'dataset_type' => 'required|mimes:json'
            ]);
```

even following codes don't works
    $this->validate($request, [

```
                'dataset_type' => 'required|file|mimes:application/json'
            ]);
```

Please anyone could she/he help me for this issue  ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try, using `mimetypes:application/json`

```
'dataset_type' => 'required|file|mimetypes:application/json'
```

Comment: i debug using this method dd(mime_content_type($_FILES['dataset_type']['tmp_name'])); i get this "text/plain"

Comment: what is your file name complete ? is it something `abc.json.txt`

Comment: tested file name is package.json